# JSON parsing in C#

Tags: c#, json

Basically I am trying to parse this JSON object and get EmailAddress, OldEmailAddress, State and ListID

```
{
    "ListID":"2ccf66750eb1b889",
    "Events":[
    {
        "Type":"Update",
        "Date":"2015-01-19 10:50:00",
        "EmailAddress":"jeff2@abc.com",
        "Name":"Lei",
        "CustomFields":[
        {
            "Key":"General School Information","Value":"Centennial (W)"},
            {"Key":"Board Information","Value":"Alert: Special Announcements"},
        ],
        "State":"Active",
        "OldEmailAddress":"jeff1@abc.com"
    }]
}
```

Here is my class structure

```
public class cmupdate
{
    public string ListID { get; set; }
    public List<Event> Events { get; set; }
}

public class CustomField
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Event
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<CustomField> CustomFields { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string OldEmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Here how I am reading the json via HTTP POST request.

```
var reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream);
var json = reader.ReadToEnd();

cmupdate events = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<cmupdate>(json);
```

I can get the ListID but having trouble gettting Event data like OldEmailAddress, EmailAddress, State, and Type.

I can get the ListID

```
string listid = events.ListID;
```

but how do I get other properties like EmailAdress which comes under Event List?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What trouble are you having, exactly? Errors? Exceptions? Can you provide an example of what doesn't work?

Comment: Can you expand on "having trouble"? Do you get an exception or is there just no data available?

Comment: I can get to ListID with events.ListID but how do I get the value for EmailAddress and etc.

Comment: The class structure is created via http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: Are you getting an exception or are unsure what to write as far as code to get these properties?

Comment: @user1424629 your code works.. what is the problem? Put a breakpoint and see the result.

Comment: code works fine to get ListID but don't know how to get other properties like EmailAddress and OldEmailAddress.

Comment: For this particular JSON example you can access these properties using, for example, `List`'s indexer: `events.Events[0].OldEmailAddress` and so on... In general case though it's strongly advised to check if a `List` contains any elements beforehand to avoid `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you all for making me think more. Here is my solution. Please let me know if I am mistaking or there is a better way.

```
var reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream);
var json = reader.ReadToEnd();
cmupdate u = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<cmupdate>(json);

string output = "";
output = "ListID: " + u.ListID;
List<Event> t = u.Events;
output += "OldEmailAddress:" + t[0].OldEmailAddress + " EmailAddress:" + t[0].EmailAddress;
```

Comment: So, what does this answer? How to use a for loop?

Comment: @EZI you are write. I initially had forloop in it but don't need any more. Thanks.